# C++ deduce function template return type when it is a pointer

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

Is it possible to automatically deduce function template return type when it is a pointer? As an example, this code won't compile unless I provide the template parameter explicitly:

```
template <typename T>
T foo() {
    return new std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
}

int main() {
    int* x = foo();
}
```

Are there any options to make the compiler deduce this return type automatically?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level. In some situation some workarounds are possible, by using temporary objects with conversion operators.

Comment: You can get close-ish.  `template <typename T> T* foo(T**) { return new T; }` and `int* x = foo(&x);`